# How can I convert HTML to XML (which conforms with XML schema or DTD)

Tags: html, xml, ubuntu, dtd, tidy

I'm trying to convert some HTML files to XML format on ubuntu and they should conform to a specific XML schema or DTD. I guess [Tidy](http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/tidylib_api_5.2.0/tidy_cmd.html) should do that but I don't understand the syntax for it. Or if there are other tools, I'd be glad to try them out. 
For instance: Convert `file.htm` to `file.xml` (which conforms to `standard.DTD`)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidy can convert HTML to XHTML (the same structure of elements and attributes but meeting the rules for XML well-formedness), but it can't convert it to meet the requirements of some arbitrary DTD.

You'll need to write an explicit mapping between the two data formats for that. XSLT is a popular language for doing that.

Comment: If I have an XSLT script. Can you suggest any programs that I could use for the transformation? I guess Visual Studio can do this, but I've tried unsuccessfuly to understand it and I'm kind of limited by time. Thanks